# Применять обфускацию или не применять?

Tags: delphi, обфускация, delphi-10-seattle

Разрабатываю программу на Delphi 10 Seatle.

Перед выпуском в продакшн, думаю провести обфускацию, однако на некоторых форумах видел, что Delphi сейчас сама производит этот процесс?
Так есть ли смысл делать это? И если есть подскажите обфускаторы.

Comment: для какой платформы будет выпуск:? Win, iOS, Android?

Comment: смысл то какой вы в этом ищите? нативный код в релиз-билде не содержит исходников, хоть сейчас хоть 20 лет назад, из exe вы обратно исходники никак не получите

Comment: @kami только для Win

Comment: @teran исходников не содержит. А rtti содержит. И этого хватает чтобы очень облегчить жизнь крекерам

Comment: `Delphi сейчас сама производит этот процесс` а можно ссылку на утверждения. Я может чего то пропустил, но вроде таких функций у компилятора нет.

Comment: @Vasek а автор использует RTTI, чтобы включать его в код? емнип, директивами компилятора они отключаются. можно оставить только для нужных вещей, и не факт что они будут иметь смысл для какого-либо "взлома".

Comment: Если беспокоит именно rtti, то вот этой директивой `{$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([]) PROPERTIES([]) FIELDS([])}` оно отключается (в пределах юнита). Но опытного крякера это вообще никак не остановит.

Comment: @teran @zed даже с `{$RTTI EXPLICIT ...` остается очень много.

Comment: @Vasek Остаются вещи связанные с GUI и системной библиотекой. Ну и от классов кое-что. Ничего сильно критичного не остаётся. Хотя, посмотреть на обфускатор (если он в природе существует) и что после него получается, было бы интересно.

Comment: @zed если мне не изменяет память самая беда, что остаются имена классов, так как нужно подержка `TObject.ClassName`. И их как раз надо изменять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обфускация применяется в случаях:

- Использование скриптовых языков, когда код распространяется "как есть" и нет возможности его откомпилировать (PHP, JavaScript)
- Когда, по каким-то причинам нужно предоставить исходные коды программы
- Когда декомпиляция является тривиальной задачей (Java)

Т.к. ваша задача не подпадает ни под один из пунктов (вам же не нужно поставлять исходные коды?) то и офусцировать программу смысла нет. Достаточно в настройках компилятора убрать генерирование отладочной информации

Единственное, что вы моете обфусцировать - это dfm код форм. Но тогда придется изобретать свой загрузчик форм